# Eclipse plugin version qualifier replacement on run/debug?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle

I have a requirement to check a plugin version number each time it runs. I am using the qualifier replacement functionality available in eclipse, but when I am just developing and run/debug from eclipse (as opposed to exporting the plugin to an archive or whatnot) the qualifier does not get replaced, e.g. version 1.2.3.qualifier stays as 1.2.3.qualifier and not changed to something like 1.2.3.201405141050, that is, the build date. I'd like the build date so it's different every time it runs. Thanks!

Comment: It is only the build system that deals with 'qualifier', there is nothing to update this when using Run / Debug.

Comment: greg, that should really be the answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From greg-449's comment: It is only the build system that deals with 'qualifier', there is nothing to update this when using Run / Debug.